# Secondary router-outlook in child component

Tags: angular, router-outlet

Am I allowed to put a secondary `router-outlet` in any other component other than the `AppComponent`? Because currently when I do this and I try to activate it using a `[routlerLink]` I get an error in the console complaining that it cannot find an outlet named popup. If I move it back to `AppComponent` it works!

So here's the structure of my project:

```
app/
├──auth/
│  └──login/
│     └──login.component.ts/html/scss
├──landing/
│  ├──landing.module.ts
│  ├──landing.routing.ts
│  └──landing.component.ts/html/scss
├──app.module.ts
├──app.routing.ts
└──app.component.ts/html/scss
```

And here's the relevant code (landing.routing/landing.component.html):

```js
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: LandingComponent,
  children: [{
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    outlet: 'popup'
  }]
}];
```

```html
<p>
  <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { popup: ['login'] } }]">Login</a>
</p>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="popup"></router-outlet>
```

...and finally the app.routing.ts routes:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'landing', loadChildren: 'app/landing/landing.module#LandingModule' },
    { path: '', component: HomepageComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
];
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a "popup router-outlet" ... but you can put content for a router-outlet in any component and route to it. You can find out much more about routing here: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-routing/table-of-contents

Comment: Thank you, yes theoretically that's what I was trying to do. I meant a secondary router-outlet that's named, and that we may use to show a component without removing another from the screen.

Comment: Can you post some of the code that is causing the error?

Comment: Yes, I'll try to do this within the next 3 to 4 hours. I'll edit my question to provide the exact code. Thank you.